# How can I make an image plane have transparency in Eevee with nodes?

Tags: image, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I have an imported model from Adobe Fuse with a basic animation. I have set up the clothes and skin to have the appropriate transparency but following the same workflow for the eyelashes does not seem to work. I have currently tried linking the file to a Diffuse BDSF and a transparent BDSF node mix shader but that doesn't seem to work out. In cycles this works out just fine but in Eevee this still shows the planes. I have checked that screen space reflections are on and that refraction is checked. Even still the render always shows the planes.

[image: picture showing the problem I am having with eyelashes rendering.]

Any advice would be appreciated and I will make sure to follow up if I am able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out just after posting, Isn't that just the way...

Anyways the answer to this question was to enable the blend mode in the materials settings to "AlphaBlend" along with the Screen Space Refraction. I also cranked the shader factor to 0.0 (I can essentially disconnect the Principled BDSF) which gave me the eyelashes I was looking for.

[image: Answer to this question]